# Can't assign correct value to a dict inside a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = 'aa'
iss = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
swhls = dict.fromkeys(iss, {a: None})

for i in iss:
    swhls[i][a] = i
print(swhls)
```

This iteration produces wrong results.

The result is:

```
{'1': {'aa': '4'}, '2': {'aa': '4'}, '3': {'aa': '4'}, '4': {'aa': '4'}}
```

However I expected:

```
{'1': {'aa': '1'}, '2': {'aa': '2'}, '3': {'aa': '3'}, '4': {'aa': '4'}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `dict.fromkeys(iss, {a: None})` you set all values to be the same object.

```
[id(v) for v in dict.fromkeys(iss, {a: None}).values()]

# [140236495531968, 140236495531968, 140236495531968, 140236495531968]
```

Thus the final value is that of the last iteration.

This is actually well described in the [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) documentation:

> classmethod fromkeys(iterable[, value])
>
> Create a new dictionary with keys from iterable and values set to value.
>
> fromkeys() is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value defaults to None. All of the values refer to just a single instance,
> **so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object
> such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict
> comprehension instead.**

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) to assign a new object to each key:

```
a = 'aa'
iss = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
swhls = {x: {a: None} for x in iss}

for i in iss:
    swhls[i][a] = i
print(swhls)
```

Output:

```
{'1': {'aa': '1'}, '2': {'aa': '2'}, '3': {'aa': '3'}, '4': {'aa': '4'}}
```